# Java language specification (jls) - annotations

Tags: java, annotations, jls

I easily found many articles on usage of annotations via Web search,  however,  when I tried to find annotations description in Java language specifications,  Web search gave link to only chapter about interfaces
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html  and in main table of contents of jls on oracle site annotations are mentioned in same interfaces chapter only. Is there a formal official description about annotations in Java and where can I read it?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the [index](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-0-index.html)? or the [table of contents](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html)?

Comment: @user207421,table of contents I wrote about in my question.  If I missed a link in table about annotations apart from part 9, please point me,  I could have missed it.  In index I followed it now and did not find definition,  only declaration place.

Comment: The *only* source of 'formal official description[s]' of language features is the JLS, and both those links provide you with all there is. Unclear what else you could possibly be looking for.

Comment: What about section 9.6.4. left you unsatisfied?

Comment: @M. Prokhorov, the section 9 is titled Interfaces.  Do you mean whole annotations description is part of interfaces?  If so,  I just be wandering why that is so - annotations were introduced together with interfaces?

Comment: @ChildDetektiv, JLS 9.6: *An annotation type declaration specifies a new annotation type, a special kind of interface type. To distinguish an annotation type declaration from a normal interface declaration, the keyword `interface` is preceded by an at-sign (`@`)*.

Comment: Look at [§9.6 Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6) and [§9.7 Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7). These are subsections of _§9 Interfaces_ because annotations are a special type of interface, just like enums are a special type of class.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov, I've read in articles that annotations are instructions to compiler,  also like documentation.  So formally e.g. `@override` is interface?

Comment: @slaw, thank you.   I will know now.  Could you point me to good tutorial where this is mentioned and used?

Comment: @ChildDetektiv, they are not instructions to compiler, they are annotations. Their primary reason to exist is documentation. They could be used for describing metadata, and some types even should be used like that in some capacity (such as `@Override` or `@FunctionalInterface`), but even then this is secondary to documenting.

Comment: @ChildDetektiv, if tutorial doesn't mention it, then either it's about something else, or it's not very good.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov, hope I do not seem carcastic,   but tutorial from oracle linked by user207421 says just 'Annotations, a form of metadata',  at least on 1st introductory page., nothing about interfaces.

Comment: @ChildDetektiv, it talks about them being interfaces in part where it discusses [how you define your own annotation types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html)

Comment: @M. Prokhorov,  I found the place,  thank you.  IMHO it is important aspect and it is downplayed unjustly,  at least it could be confusing to a novice. Thanx for explanations and your time!

Comment: @Child You can't selectively quote from the Java Tutorial, and effectively claim that if it isnt written there it doesn't exist,  when the JLS sections referenced here state clearly that annotations are a special form of interface.

Comment: @user207421,  I considered annotations major feature,  not part of other feature,  hence it resulted in misunderstanding.

Comment: @M. Prokhorov, beg you pardon,  I've skimmed to the end of 9th, so I saw declaration of types and invocation in form of markers (annotations).  It is not explained what result invocation of such special type should bring (except for certain built-ins). Only said `associates information with program construct`.  Is it described in JLS?

Comment: @ChildDetektiv, as it specificaly says: *associates information with program construct* ***but has no effect at run time***. However, since you can get access to certain annotations during compile time or even runtime (based on `RetentionPolicy`, accessible via reflection mechanisms), some compiler extension or libraries built upon annotations to make program behave a certain way (or make additional compile-time validations for the code).

Comment: Annotations don't provide behavior on their own. For added compile-time behavior (validations, code generation, etc) one has to implement an annotation [`Processor`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html). For added run-time behavior the annotation must be annotated with `@RetentionPolicy(RUNTIME)` and the application has to query [`AnnotatedElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AnnotatedElement.html)s; in other words, via reflection constructs (e.g. `Class`, `Method`, etc).

Comment: Some tools can provide validation and common bug checking by inspecting the class files, in which case the annotations must have _at least_ `@RetentionPolicy(CLASS)`. Besides all that annotations also provide documentation; however, to have them show up in Javadoc they must be annotated with `@Documented`.

Answer (score 2):

An annotation denotes a specific invocation of an annotation type (§9.6) and usually provides values for the elements of that type. And in 9.6 it is said that annotation type is special interface type.

[9.7. Annotations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7)

> 9.7. Annotations
>
> An annotation is a marker which associates information with a program construct, but has no effect at run time. An annotation denotes a specific invocation of an annotation type (§9.6) and usually provides values for the elements of that type.

[9.6. Annotation Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6)

> 9.6. Annotation Types
>
> An annotation type declaration specifies a new annotation type, a special kind of interface type. To distinguish an annotation type declaration from a normal interface declaration, the keyword interface is preceded by an at-sign (@).

That's why they are described in that (*9. Interfaces*) section of JLS.

Also it is explained in tutorial on Oracle website (although not right from the start):

[Declaring an Annotation Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html)

*Acknowledgement: answer based on help provided in comments.*